# excel:find total_log of the max date for each group

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hava a sheet1 like and it will update eveyday:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| company |   date   | total_log |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| A       | 20180910 |     32987 |
| A       | 20180902 |       426 |
| A       | 20180905 |     42135 |
| B       | 20180906 |     64743 |
| B       | 20180910 |    235647 |
| B       | 20180902 |      2346 |
| C       | 20180804 |     67536 |
| C       | 20180910 |     34536 |
| C       | 20180510 |    235356 |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

how to udate date and total_log column on sheet2 based on sheet1 with the max date for each company automaticly by Excel

```
+---------+------+-----------+
| company | date | total_log |
+---------+------+-----------+
| A       |      |           |
| B       |      |           |
| C       |      |           |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Edit your post & write Date value in proper format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**How it Works:**

1. Write this Array formula to get Latest date in 
   Cell `B3` of `Sheet 2`, finish with 
   `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill down.

`{=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$11=A3,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$11))}`

2. To get the Total of log for Group A for Latest Date write this Formula in Cell `C3` of `Sheet 2` & fill down.

   `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C3:C11,Sheet1!A3:A11,A3,Sheet1!B3:B11,B3)`

**Note,** *adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you #J. Cooker,, keep asking ☺